# full calendar js date in wrong place

Tags: jquery, calendar

I met some trouble while usign jquery full calenda.js

I have many dates from database so I generated a code like that

```
events: [
                <?php while ($tache= mysql_fetch_assoc($liste_tache)): ?>
                {
                    title: '<?php echo $tache['libelle'] ?>',
                    start: new Date(<?php echo day($tache['date_tache'],'Y') ?>, <?php echo day($tache['date_tache'],'m') ?>, <?php echo day($tache['date_tache'],'d') ?>, <?php echo day($tache['date_tache'],'H') ?>, <?php echo day($tache['date_tache'],'i') ?>),
                    allDay: false
                },
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            {
                    title: 'test',
                    start: new Date(2013, 10, 08, 07, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
            ]
```

and to see if it is all ok I added an event manually.

in fact the trouble is that the date 2013,10,08 is set at the end of the calendar it seems to be in an other month. (Time is set to 24h) in fact it must be in the yellow case (date of the day)

[image: my calendar]

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: that's weird I've never seen something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not related to fullcalendarjs. Instead its related to new Date().

According to Date documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

new Date returns current date so you don't need to call new Date with parameters for current date.

You have to use only Date

```
        {
            title: 'test',
            start: Date(2013, 10, 08, 07, 30),
            allDay: false
        }

         or simply

         {
            title: 'test',
            start: Date(), //for current date
            allDay: false
        }
```

It should work fine. Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abhishek_gahlot/VZvC8/1/

Comment: than you it was really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

While Abhishek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19246101/1011186) helped the OP with his/her issue, I believe it doesn't properly relay the principles behind Javascript's Date.

The proper reason as to why he's getting the events added to the next month is because the month parameter of Date objects starts with 0 (January) and runs to 11 (December). That means he should be using the following parameters if he wants to add an event on the 8th of October 2013

```
    {
        title: 'test',
        start: new Date(2013, 9, 8, 07, 30), // Note that the month parameter is 9, not 10
        allDay: false
    }
```

Also, as Abhishek has mentioned, invoking the Javascript Date as a function without the 'new'  keyword will yield a date object representing the current date and time. That means you do not have to supply any parameter to Date to get the current date. See the following:

```
    {
        title: 'test',
        start: Date(), // This will return the current date and time AS A STRING
        allDay: false
    }
```

While this is not logically different than using Date(2013, 10, 08, 07, 30), not supplying the parameters is more preferable as it is more clear that you want the current date and time and not some other date. The extra parameters will just confuse you/other developers of your intent.

In case you want to get the current date and time as a Date object and not a string, use the new keyword without supplying any parameters.